Existence of asymptotic sequence in Ergodic Measure-Preserving transformations
Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $T:X\to X$ be an ergodic measure-preserving transformation. We assume that $T$ satisfies the property that if $B \in \mathcal{F}$ and $T^{-1}B \subseteq B$, then $B = T^{-1}B \, (\text{mod } \mu)$.
Consider a set $A \in \mathcal{F}$ with $0 < \mu(A) < +\infty$ for which the following holds:
$$
\int_A \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \chi_A \circ T^k \right)^2 d\mu \leq \lambda \left( \int_A \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \chi_A \circ T^k \right) d\mu \right)^2, \quad \forall n \geq 1,
$$
for some constant $\lambda > 0$. Under these assumptions, we aim to establish the existence of a sequence of constants $(\theta_n)_n$ increasing to infinity such that:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\theta_n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \mu(B \cap T^{-k} C) = \mu(B) \mu(C), \quad \forall B,C \in \mathcal{F}, \text{ with } B,C \subseteq A.
$$
If we assume that $ \mu(X) < \infty $, then by the Mean Ergodic Theorem, we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \mu(B \cap T^{-k} C) = \frac{\mu(B) \mu(C)}{\mu(X)}.
$$
However, if $ \mu(X) = \infty $, the Ergodic Theorem implies that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \mu(B \cap T^{-k} C) = 0.
$$
In my case, I would like to construct a sequence $ (\theta_n)_n $ such that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\theta_n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \mu(B \cap T^{-k} C) = \mu(B) \mu(C),
$$
when $ \mu(X) = \infty $.
I believe this relates to the concept of weak mixing. While attempting to construct a sequence $(\theta_n)_n$, I considered using $\theta_n = \frac{1}{\mu(A)^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\mu(A\cap T^{-k}A)$. However, I am having difficulty proving the limit. Could you please assist me with this? Thank you!

It looks like what you are trying to prove is the main result from this paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02761661.  The paper shows that rational ergodicity implies weak rational ergodicity.  These definitions are also shown in this paper which is freely available: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.06566.  The scaling factor that you wrote above is what Aaronson used.
